# Correct HTML when translate website via Google Translate API?

Tags: html, api, tags, google-translate

When translating a URL (such as https://www.straatmakershop.nl/) via the free Google Translate tool (https://translate.google.com/) this often results in 'broken' pages. It seems Google is trying to 'optimize' the HTML by removing/adding HTML tags, which in many cases ends up breaking the layout or stop the CSS from being applied correctly.

1. Does anyone have experience with the paid Google Translate API (https://cloud.google.com/translate/) for translating URLs? How well does it work?
2. Are HTML tags being added/changed automatically? Can you easily change settings preventing them from being added?
3. Do the pages look close-to-identical after translation? Any examples?
4. Is it possible to generate publicly accessible URLs that you can link to (such as https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.straatmakershop.nl%2F)?

Comment: I couldn't recreate the broken pages Theo.  But my initial thought was "why would even care about translating?".  Why would someone outside the Netherlands buy tools from you when they are likely available locally to them, at about the same price?  Are you sure it is worth the effort?

Comment: If you look at the original https://www.straatmakershop.nl/ it shows the green 'order now' buttons (scroll down a bit) properly, while the translated version shows a green 'mesh of buttons' instead (because Google Translate added multiple <a> elements to the page). I want to be able to show a flawless translated version to non-Dutch people so they can rate the UI/UX :)

Comment: Theo, have a look at this screenshot of an English translated page. https://gyazo.com/01177fe0cf04efe79ad4279defa33a8c  The buttons look fine in Chrome.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/asking